# How do I add email address to MailChimp list using API

Tags: php, mailchimp

I am trying to use MailChimp API 3.0 to add an email address to existing list using this code below but it keeps throwing this **error** message. Please can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

> 401 : Your API key may be invalid, or you've attempted to access the
>   wrong datacenter.

Code:

```
$apikey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-us9";
$list_id = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$MD5_hashed_email_address = md5(strtolower($to_email));
$auth = base64_encode("user:$apikey");

$data = array(
    "apikey" => $apikey,
    "email_address" => $to_email,
    "status" => "subscribed",
    "merge_fields" => array(
        "FNAME" => $firstname,
        "LNAME" => $surname
    )
);
$json_data = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://us9.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/$list_id/members/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json",
    'Authorization: apikey ' . $auth));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "PHP-MCAPI/2.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json",
    'Authorization: Basic ' . $auth));`